# WP-Calendar Saturday will not show

Tags: fullcalendar

My problem is very simple to say.  In the graphical calendar which I called for in one of my pages. Despite setting the parameters and reading the documentation, I can get every day of the week to show up in the calendar except for Saturday.  I wouldn't care so much except I run a internet radio show and one of my specialty shows is on a Saturday.  I'd like for it to be able to show all seven days in the full month view.  I really like the layout and design of your calendar, but your parameters make my head spin.  I set the weekends to true, because I thought from what I read would make them display.  I guess I was wrong.  I'm not a programmer of web designer yet.  I start school in the fall.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around these settings.  Please help.

You may visit my page directly to see what I mean.

http://www.loftonspace.com/home/radio/

Thank You for any help.
P.S.  I realize people just don't give out help for free, so to the person who helps the most resolve my issue, I have a special place at the footer of my site for special thanks to people who helped with the site.  I would be willing to add a link there to a professional website.
 Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width of the calendar. It is showing the fullCalendar completely, but the overflow is hidden behind the smaller div you placed the calendar in. Make the available space smaller and that should fix the problem...

As for the promotion... If my answer is accepted, use Stackoverflow as the promotion as I do not run any kind of professional establishment. I just do my own projects.

I am not in a position where I can further inspect the code and give you a proper answer, but you can use firebug to find the class/id of the div you need to change. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The div setting solved the problem. The calender is displaying properly now. I now have one more tiny problem and then this mini project of mine will be complete. In the calender when a user clicks on an event, I'd like it to take them to the page I set up for the event page. I only want the event that they selected in the full graphical calender to be displayed. How do I set this up. I've tried reading through the documentation and I followed what I could. I'm not a web developer yet. I don't quite understand this. Step by step instructions would be very helpful.

Comment: Just a follow up. I figured it out.  I didn't have all the parameters set up for the page to read everything about the event.  Forget I asked anything else from you.  Sometimes you just need to walk away from something and then go back to it to figure it out.  I was eating lunch when it dawned on me what I was doing wrong.  I will have a link to your plugin by the end of the day today. THANK YOU.  You got the spark going for me to figure this out.

Comment: The link is up.  The footer link links to http://www.faebusoft.ch/webentwicklung/wpcalendar/  I hope this is okay.  If not, just let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thats not my link. I just wanted you to promote Stack Overflow. LOL